# Linear approximation to the Herfindahl-Hirschman index

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, approximation

Suppose I have an $n\times m$ matrix of nonnegative real numbers

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} & \cdots & x_{1,n} \\
x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} & \cdots & x_{2,n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{m,1} & x_{m,2} & \cdots & x_{m,n} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where the column totals are denoted $x_{\cdot j}=\sum_i x_{ij}$ and the row totals are denoted $x_{i\cdot}=\sum_j x_{ij}$.

I would like to approximate the [Herfindahl---Hirschman index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herfindahl%E2%80%93Hirschman_index) of the column totals,

$$
\frac{\sum_j x_{\cdot j}^2}{(\sum_j x_{\cdot j})^2}, \tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$

by a weighted average of row-specific Herfindahl---Hirschman indices:

$$
\sum_i \left(\frac{x_{i\cdot}}{\sum_i x_{i\cdot}}\right) 
\left(\frac{\sum_j x_{ij}^2}{(\sum_j x_{ij})^2}\right) \tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$

This is a first-order (linear) approximation. My question is: can we say anything about the approximation error, like whether it is negative (indicating concavity) and/or bounded, in general or perhaps as $n\to\infty$?

The Herfindahl---Hirschman index can also be viewed as a sum of squared probabilities, or the [collision probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4015904/sum-of-squared-probability-distribution-sum-c-p-c2-is-a-measure-of-uncertain).

**What I have tried so far**

For the special case of $m=2,n=3$, I worked out the approximation error (i.e. \eqref{eq1} minus \eqref{eq2}) to be

$$
-2\left(\sum_i\sum_j x_{ij}\right)^{-2} \left[
x_{11}x_{22}+x_{11}x_{23}+x_{12}x_{21}+x_{12}x_{23}+x_{13}x_{21}+x_{13}x_{22} \\
-(x_{11}x_{12}+x_{11}x_{13}+x_{12}x_{13})\frac{x_{21}+x_{22}+x_{23}}{x_{11}+x_{12}+x_{13}} \\
-(x_{21}x_{22}+x_{21}x_{23}+x_{22}x_{23})\frac{x_{11}+x_{12}+x_{13}}{x_{21}+x_{22}+x_{23}}
\right], 
$$

which shows that we have a negative term on the outside of the square brackets, and a term of unknown sign and magnitude on the inside of the square brackets.

I have a specific application in mind, with $m=6$ and $n=162$. When I try the approximation on many such arrays in my data, I end up with the performance in the figure below. The approximation errors are all negative, suggesting that the Herfindahl---Hirschman index is concave.

[image: real-world application of the approximation]

This question is similar to, but more specific than, this unanswered one: [Decomposing Simpson's Diversity Index/Herfindahl Index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3995710/decomposing-simpsons-diversity-index-herfindahl-index).